# Badges in achievements dropdown should not have custom designs from sites they weren't earned on

Tags: feature-request, badges, design

I earned a badge on Ask Different. I found out about this via the achievements dropdown while I was hanging out on Science Fiction & Fantasy:

[image]

The badge in the dropdown is the icon that comes with the SciFi site design even though it is a badge on a different site. This is confusing, especially on a site like SciFi where the badge design is so distinctive. It makes me think I somehow earned a badge on SciFi for a question I asked on Ask Different.

If I view the dropdown on Ask Different, it looks better:

[image]

Badges in the achievements dropdown should either:

1. Use the icon that corresponds with the site on which the badge was earned (instead of the site you're currently on), or
2. Use a generic icon in all cases (the [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges) or [beta site](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/badges) designs come to mind)